# document.getElementById breaks the code

Tags: javascript, post, methods, getelementbyid

**JavaScript**

```
document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);

var screenres='test';
document.write(screenres);
document.write('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');

document.getElementById('resolutionfield').value = screenres;
document.write(screenres);
document.write('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
```

I am trying to get the users screen resolution and pass it into an HTML post method. This snippet only prints out `1368x768testBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB` if I disable the `document.getElementById` line by adding two slashes in front of it, it prints everything out perfectly.

**JavaScript**

```
document.write(screen.width+'x'+screen.height);

var screenres='test';
document.write(screenres);
document.write('BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB');

//document.getElementById('resolutionfield').value = screenres;
document.write(screenres);
document.write('AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA');
```

I am playing with this for the last 4 hours. It might be a simple problem but I just not able to figure it out.

Further down in my code

```
document.getElementById('secondsfield').value = seconds;
document.getElementById('minutesfield').value = minutes;
document.getElementById('hoursfield').value = hours;
```

these variables get passed on into the post method without any problems

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="usersipaddress" name="usersipaddress" value= "<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];?>" >
<input type="hidden" id="secondsfield" name="secondsfield" value="" >
<input type="hidden" id="minutesfield" name="minutesfield" value="" >
<input type="hidden" id="hoursfield" name="hoursfield" value="" >
<input type="hidden" id="resolutionfield" name="resolutionfield" value="screenres" >
```

Anybody has the answer to this?

Comment: I suggest you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: What error do you get? Where is the script placed (in relation to the inputs)?

Comment: Do the elements exist yet? JavaScript runs while the DOM is being constructed.

Comment: Is the `.js` *after* the element in question?

Comment: I only used document.write to try to debug my code. It does not appear in my original code. I could not figure out why is my variable not passed on.

Comment: [I don't see anything wrong.](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/gEpmi)

Comment: I don't get any errors, it just stops printing after the getelementbyid part.

Comment: @AlexFord Your example may have introduced a "*fix*" compared to the OP's code -- the `<script>` is after the `<input>`.

Comment: @Jonathan After reading an answer below I thought the same thing :)

Comment: @Sandor Click [here](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/gEpmi) to see your code working. Click [here](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/buKFo) to see how it fails by moving the input. Remember that the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) is built by parsing the HTML document from top to bottom. If your script references elements that exist below the script then the browser has not processed them yet; they don't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this line:

```
document.getElementById('resolutionfield').value = screenres;
```

is executed too early before the `resolutionfield` DOM element has been parsed and thus is present in the DOM, then this will cause an error and stop execution of your script.  That's because:

```
document.getElementById('resolutionfield')
```

will be `null` and then when you try to reference the `.value` property, it will not work and will generate the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null` which you can see in the browser's error console or debug console.

Comment: This is correct :). @Sandor Click [here](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/gEpmi) to see your code working. Click [here](http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/buKFo) to see how it fails by moving the input.